# Texture Coordinates are slightly off when rendering to FBO texture

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm working on a WebGL OpenGL ES project that renders my scene to a texture and then uses that texture to render to the window.

I noticed that this causes an odd shimmering on the edges of textures. When I revert the project back to rendering directly to the window the shimmering goes away.

The FBO is set to the same size as the window and the texture is drawn to the window pixel for pixel.

What is causing this to happen? Is it fixable? I am using GL_NEAREST on the FBO texture and GL_LINEAR on all other textures. I'd rather not use GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE as that would cause other problems.

[[image: render to screen]]
[image: render to fbo]

**Framebuffer creation**

```
/* Returns true if a framebuffer object is created */
Display.prototype.createFramebuffer = function(name) {
  var gl = this.gl; // Sanity Save

  var size = 1024;

  var fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
  fb.width = size;
  fb.height = size;

  var tex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, fb.width, fb.height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

  var rb = gl.createRenderbuffer();
  gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, rb);
  gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, fb.width, fb.height);
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
  gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, rb);

  if(gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) !== gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) { return false; }

  this.fbo[name] = {fb: fb, rb: rb, tex: tex};

  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
  gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, null);
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);

  return true;
};
```

**Before drawing scene**

```
/* Draw Geometry */
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.fbo.world.fb); // Enable world framebuffer
gl.viewport(0, 0, this.window.width, this.window.height); // Resize to canvas
gl.clearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);  // Opaque grey backdrop
```

Comment: How is your FBO setup? Same size and format as the screen? Are you using OpenGL or OpenGL-es? Show the relevant code.

Comment: @BDL Added the setup code. It is same size and format as the screen. OpenGL ES as that's what WebGL uses.

Comment: So it actually is WebGL? All three versions, Desktop-OpenGL, OpenGL-es and WebGL have their own limitations and restrictions. Tagging your question with the right one ensures that you don't get answers that do not apply to your environment.

Comment: Yeah I said WebGL on the first line of the question heh. Didn't know I needed to tag it as a specific opengl version. I just used the suggested ones.

Comment: If you turn off anti-aliasing do you get the same results in the canvas? `canvas.getContext("webgl", {antialias: false});`

Comment: @gman I will give that a shot as soon as I start working. I'll let you know in an hour or so. Does setting anti-alias on the canvas also apply it to the framebuffer?

Comment: @gman I actually read your message wrong earlier. I tried disabling AA on the branch of my project that renders directly to the window and it caused the same shimmering edge issue. So the issue is that my FBO is not anti-aliased? I'll go look into it and see if I can fix this now. Thanks!

Comment: I implemented an FXAA post processing shader and it didn't seem to do much. 

I also added a upscale factor that will render the scene at 2x resolution  and will sample with GL_LINEAR when rendering to the window. That minimized the shimmering effect a lot but it's really inefficient. Are there any better ways to go about this? Should the FXAA filter be more effective for this?

Answer (score 0):

*After a push in the right direction (and plenty of trial and error) I figured out the problem.*

The reason this is happening is because hardware anti-aliasing is disabled when rendering to an FBO texture. In order to fix it you need to implement your own AA.

To fix this for my project I attempted a crude MSAA post shader in combination with upscaling my FBO render to 2x the window resolution and that reduced the shimmering to a nearly unnoticeable level.

FXAA might be another good solution but I couldn't get it to work for me personally.

*If there are some better ways to go about this let me know!*

Comment: I would say it another way. The issue is that whatever you're doing is anti-alias sensitive. I think I'd try to make it not antialias sensitive rather than how to do antialiasing on the FBO.

Comment: @gman From what I have read WebGL does not support anti-aliasing when rendering to a FBO texture. Some of the sources for this info were a bit old (1-2 years). If you can find some solid references to the contrary I'd love to find a better way to handle this. I don't like having to use my own AA methods as they are inefficient. Also I really appreciate the help. I feel like I get completely ignored on here to often.